# clarification on when does ajax call within document.ready gets triggered

Tags: javascript, ajax, pageload, page-load-time

If I've a page which contains below:

```
1. HTML with text and images.
2. Lots of reference to CSS and Large JS Files.
3. Within HTML a call similar to one below:

$(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
      url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
      beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
      }
    })
      .done(function( data ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
          console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
        }
      });
      }
```

Could someone please clarify if my understanding below is correct, in terms of which one gets loaded first?

1. Load all HTML and Images.
2. Load CSS and apply CSS Styles
3. Then, invoke $.ajax call.
4. Render whole page.

Comment: Use `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` if you need the entire page to be done loading before running the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ready` is guaranteed to be invoked after the DOM is ready, nothing more. This definitely will **not** have loaded "all HTML and images", specifically images may or may not have been loaded.

Comment: DOM is the in-memory representation of your document, yes.